# Is it possible to have different CSS for different screen sizes within a class

Tags: css

Currently, I am using @media to define different CSS for different screen sizes

```
@media (max-width: 1800){
    body{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1800){
    body{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

I am having trouble making sure to update both resolution's CSS when I make a change because they are located far from each other.

Is there a way to internalize the screen size to inside the class?

ie:

```
body{
    @media (max-width: 1800){    
        font-size: 14px;    
    }
    @media (min-width: 1800){    
        font-size: 16px;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Not with plain CSS. If you use a preprocessor such as SCSS then yes.

Comment: Sidenote: Be aware that for **exactly** 1800px (you missed to specify the unit there, too) **both** media queries will match.

Comment: +1 to the @Turnip comment, also, it will be probably better if you set a default and use the media queries only to apply the difference between the default and the desired for this query

Comment: Why don't you just move the media queries closer together?

Comment: They are sequential, but there's over 100 classes in each.

Comment: @Turnip If I were to use scss, do you have a good example I can reference about how to do what I'm asking?

Comment: @user1637466 the part under "ie" is exactly what you can do with scss

Comment: Note that this is not a good example of how to use media queries. You should take either a desktop-first or a mobile-first approach - that is, start with what you want to be the "default" settings first (outside of any query), and then write the queries as only max-width or only min-width values. The latter is preferred, for various reasons.

Comment: @MrLister right now I have the classes outside of the media that contain things that are constant across the two - namely, things such as display, position, background-color, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't include media queries inside the declaration block of a css rule.

However, it sounds like your issue may be primarily related to organizing quite a bit more css than you included in your example to simplify the process of making changes to specific selectors. If that is the case, then it may help you to use more than one media query for the same breakpoint. This may help you organize your css for simpler maintenance (locate related css rules closer together), but it does add bloat to your code due to the repeating `@media` rules (whether the bloat is a reasonable tradeoff for simplifying the maintenance process is up to you).

For example:

```
/* body styles */

body {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 1800px) {
  /* body styles for 1800px and above */
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}


/* h1 styles */

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 1800px) {
  /* h1 styles for the same media breakpoint as above */
  h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
```